# jQuery accordion with multiple UL elements

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-ui-accordion, slideup

I am using jQuery to produce an accordion effect in a menu I have created. The menu is tabbed and uses jQuery UI Tabs and in accordance with their documentation I cannot use multiple effects on one element. As such, I have used slideUp() and slideToggle() to create the effect which works, a la `<a onclick="$('ul#categories li ul').slideUp();$(this).next().slideToggle()">Subjects</a>`.

However, my list has another unordered list within it and this does not get displayed. I do not want to have lots of links set to activate the slider as this gets very complex to maintain within my CMS which outputs the links as lists. An example of my code would be

```
<div id="member-categories">
<ul id="categories">
    <li>
        <a onclick="$('ul#categories li ul ').slideUp();$(this).next().slideToggle()">Heading 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="$('ul#categories li ul').slideUp();$(this).next().slideToggle()">Heading 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If I click Heading 1, only Link 1 and 2 are displayed. Clicking Heading 2 displays all links. Why is the `<ul>` of Link 1 in Heading 1 not displaying?

Thanks

Comment: there is not any <ul id="categories"> :S

Comment: I think the problem is to do with the `next()` call, although I don't understand why it gets the next 2 <li> but not the <ul> in an <li>. `find()` and 'children()` won't work because the elements are not children of <a>. Really stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like this for you're looking for?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uetGd/3/)

When you're selecting '#Categories li ul' this is hiding all inner list and list items. When you use slideDown on the first unordered list, it will only show (change the display property of) its direct children (in other words, the inner list and list items are still hidden). The inner list items display property is still set to 'display:none'. Instead if you 'show' each 'ul' then its direct children (each li) will be shown.

Edit: Alternativly (as the demo demonstrates), you can just hide the first set of un-ordered lists.

```
$('#categories').children().children('ul').slideUp();
```

This way, the inner lists are technically still shown. So when you show the outer list, all its children are shown.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much, I had been struggling for ages with that! If I had another list that I wanted to do the same thing with, say id=archive, is there a way I can do it with just that code or do I need to use an if-else statement and check for the id of the list?

Comment: No problem. Instead of selecting the list by specifying the id which the 'header' is contained, you can access it by using .parent() to traverse to the required node - in your case, when a header is clicked you can use $(this).parent().parent() and do the same as before - see http://jsfiddle.net/uetGd/4/ :)

Comment: Thanks. That is much simpler than the massive if statement I was starting to code! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="$('ul#categories li ul').slideUp();$(this).next('ul').slideToggle()">Subjects</a>
```

how about that?

Comment: That doesn't do it unfortunately. If I add `;$('ul#categories li ul li ul').slideToggle()` to the end of the first `<a onclick=...>` I get the desired result. I then tested it by putting a nested `<ul>` in the second list without updating the second anchor tag and it caused both lists to function correctly. If I then duplicated the anchor tags I get the same error. Why does this work? I'm new to jQuery so still trying to get the hang of it all.

Comment: I understand what the first statement is collapsing all the list items and that the second is then expanding the next element after the anchor tag. Why then does the unordered list not expand with it? Why does my addition in one anchor tag affect another anchor tag?